# VBA: make calculation - output just value

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new with VBA and I was hoping someone could help me. I would like to create a macro that makes a calculation but returns just the value. I have two specific examples where I would like to do this:
-One is where the macro calculates the average of A2:A100 and return the Value of that average in B100, then the average between A3:A101 and return the value in B101, and so in until B700
-The second case is where the macro finds cell containing the Max value in cells A2:A101, and return that value in cell E1.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: At the moment you haven't given us any indication of why you are having troubles writing this yourself.  So please let us know which part of writing the code is causing you problems.  Perhaps even include the code you have written and explain further why it isn't doing what you want it to do.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options for doing any sort of calculation (which I assume is going to be more involved than replicating the built-in functionality of `AVERAGE()`, `SUM()` or `MAX()`).

1. **User Defined Function (UDF)** - Create a `Function` that returns a single value (like `Double`, `String` or `Variant` array). This function can take numeric or range arguments, and optionally it can reference values from the active worksheet and returns the calculated value of the cell it was invoked from. Here are two examples:
2. **Manual Calculation** - Create a `Subroutine` that reads values and/or files and manually updates the values of cells before it exits. This method is required when more than one cell needs to written. It also requires a trigger, such as a button to press, or a menu item to click, or some other event to call the subroutine. There is two ways to process a table of cells. One is direct using the `.Cell()` method, and the other is the faster one taking all the values into an array and writing out all the values with *one command*.

### Example UDF Code (in a Module)

```
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : MySquare
' Author    : ja72
' Date      : 10/29/2017
' Purpose   : Returns `x^2/c` where c is defined in cell [B2]
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'
Public Function MySquare(ByVal x As Double) As Double
    Dim c As Double
    c = [B2]
    ' Same as:  c = ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Value
    MySquare = x ^ 2 / c
End Function

'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : MyAverage
' Author    : ja72
' Date      : 10/29/2017
' Purpose   : Uses the built-in funcrtion 'Average()` on the input cells
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'
Public Function MyAverage(ByVal r As Range) As Double
    MyAverage = WorksheetFunction.Average(r)
End Function
```

### Example worksheet layout

[image: ex1]

### Example Manual Calculations (in a Sheet)

```
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : FillMultiplicationTableDirect
' Author    : John
' Date      : 10/29/2017
' Purpose   : Fills a n×n table of cells directly
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'
Public Sub FillMultiplicationTableDirect(ByVal n As Long)

    Dim r_table As Range
    ' Start from top left cell B15
    Set r_table = Range("B15")
    ' Process the cells one by one
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = 1 To n
        For j = 1 To n
            ' Write the resuling cell directly
            r_table.Cells(i, j).Value = i * j
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub

'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : FillMultiplicationTableOffline
' Author    : John
' Date      : 10/29/2017
' Purpose   : Fills a n×n table of cells with an array
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'
Public Sub FillMultiplicationTableOffline(ByVal n As Long)

    Dim r_table As Range
    ' Start from top left cell B15 and grab n×n cells
    Set r_table = Range("B15").Resize(n, n)
    ' Define an array with the values
    Dim res() As Variant
    ' Fill the array with the existing values of the cells
    res = r_table.Value
    'Process the array (offline calculation)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = 1 To n
        For j = 1 To n
            res(i, j) = i * j
        Next j
    Next i
    ' Write the array back to the worksheet
    r_table.Value = res

End Sub
```

The above functions need to be triggered manually with a command like

```
Call Sheet1.FillMultiplicationTableDirect(10)
```

or

```
Call Sheet1.FillMultiplicationTableOffline(10)
```

### Example Result

[image: ex2]

Comment: Your `MySquare` function needs to be marked as `Volatile` or else a change to cell B2 will not recalculate the answer.  This will be inefficient as **any** change to the workbook will force a recalculation.  A better way would be to pass B2 as a parameter to the function, thus allowing Excel to know when (and when not) to recalculate the function.

Comment: @YowE3K - Learn something new every day. I know it would be better to pass a parameter, but I wanted to demonstrate that UDF functions _can_ read values (not write them). Also, I have clearly labeled the value at `[B2]` as constant.

Answer (score 0):

You need User defined `Function`s instead of `Sub`s.
Then in the needed cell (say, B100) you enter `=MyFunc(A2:A100)`.
In your case, it seems you can copy-paste down.
The assignment could be done at the VBA level also, with `Range("B100").Formula = MyFunc(...`

This, with a little googling, should quickly get you going.

Among many references out there:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-custom-functions-in-Excel-2f06c10b-3622-40d6-a1b2-b6748ae8231f

Comment: Instead of `=MyFunc(A2:A100)`, the OP could use `=AVERAGE(A2:A100)` (i.e. no need for a UDF) in cell B100 and copy-paste down.  And the formula, if entered via VBA, would look like `Range("B100").Formula = "=MyFunc(..."` or `Range("B100").Formula = "=AVERAGE(..."` (or even `Range("B100:B700").Formula = "=AVERAGE(..."`)

Comment: @YowE3K - Clearly there is no need for an UDF. But the OP stated "I would like to create a macro that makes a calculation but returns just the value". It is ok to add another option anyway.